# How to sort a List<Person> with sometimes equal entries?

Tags: c#, wpf, list, sorting

I have a question regarding sorting in C#.

Lets assume that there is `List<Person> personList` with 50 items.
Each `Person` has `string forename, surname`.

Now I would like to sort this list of persons.
First of all the list shall be sorted by the `Forename`.
Therefor I would use this:
`personList.Sort((p1, p2)=>string.Compare(p1.Forename, p2.Forname, true));`

After this I would like to sort all entries with the same `Forname` by their `Surname`.

How can I do this?

Edit:
@Russ Cam: Here is an example list.

Unsorted:

```
David Johnson
William Black
David Smith
Matthew Edwards
Jayden Anderson
Andrew Connor
Adam Johnson
Daniel Armstrong
Steve Anderson
Daniel Black
```

Sorted:

```
Adam Johnson
Andrew Connor
Daniel Armstrong
Daniel Black
David Johnson
David Smith
Jayden Anderson
Matthew Edwards
Steve Anderson
William Black
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works perfectly

```
personList.Sort((p1, p2)=>string.Compare(p1.Forename+p1.Surname, p2.Forname+ p2.Surname, true));
```

Answer (score 8):

You could use LINQ's [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx) method to do this

```
var sortedPersonList = personList.OrderBy(p => p.Forename).ThenBy(p => p.Surname);
```

**EDIT:**

Here's a complete console application to verify that this returns results in the order that you expect

```
static void Main()
{
    var personList = new List<Person>{
        new Person("David Johnson"),
        new Person("William Black"),
        new Person("David Smith"),
        new Person("Matthew Edwards"),
        new Person("Jayden Anderson"),
        new Person("Andrew Connor"),
        new Person("Adam Johnson"),
        new Person("Daniel Armstrong"),
        new Person("Steve Anderson"),
        new Person("Daniel Black")  
    };

    var sortedPersonList = personList.OrderBy(p => p.Forename).ThenBy(p => p.Surname);

    foreach (var person in sortedPersonList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(person);
    }

    Console.Read();
}

public class Person
{
    public Person(string name)
    {
        var names = name.Split(' ');
        Forename = names[0];
        Surname = names[1];
    }

    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

public override string ToString()
{
    return Forename + " " + Surname;
}
}
```

which writes out

```
Adam Johnson
Andrew Connor
Daniel Armstrong
Daniel Black
David Johnson
David Smith
Jayden Anderson
Matthew Edwards
Steve Anderson
William Black
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work for me. Had 25 persons in the list with the same `Forename` and different `Surname` but you solution doesn't sort at all in this case. Don't know why but thanks for you answer :)

Comment: @TorbenJonas could you add the list or persons that you want to sort to the question and the expected sort order?

Answer (score 2):

You can let `Person` implement `System.IComparable<Person>`.

```
public class Person : IComparable<Person>
{
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(Person other)
    {
        int comp = Forename.CompareTo(other.Forename);
        if (comp != 0) {
            return comp;
        }
        return Surname.CompareTo(other.Surname);
    }
}
```

With this definition you can sort directly with

```
personList.Sort();
```

---

You can also pass an `IComparer<T>` to the `Sort` method. This allows you define different sortings for persons (by name, by age, by salary etc.).

```
public class ComparePersonsByName : IComparer<Peron>
{
    public static readonly ComparePersonsByName Instance = 
        new ComparePersonsByName();

    private ComparePersonsByName()
    {
    }

    public int Compare(Person x, Person y)
    {
        int comp = x.Forename.CompareTo(y.Forename);
        if (comp != 0) {
            return comp;
        }
        return x.Surname.CompareTo(y.Surname);
    }
}
```

Now you can sort with

```
personList.Sort(ComparePersonsByName.Instance);
```

Note: I am using a variant of the singleton pattern here.

---

You might have to add tests for `null` references in a real life scenario.

Comment: Thanks for you extensive answer. Even if I didn't took you solution I definetly will try it out sometime. :)